# SwiftUI Scroll Text to First Range of Substring?

Tags: swiftui, swift5, ios15

In my SwiftUI (iOS 15) app I have a screen that displays a potentially lengthy string, allowing the user to scroll vertically:

```
struct TextScrollView: View {
    var formattedText: AttributedString
    var searchTerm: String?

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text(self.formattedText)
        }
        .padding(.all)
        .font(.body)
    } //body
} //TextScrollView
```

My desired behavior is that if a searchTerm is passed to the view and that searchTerm is present at least once in the formattedText, then the text automatically scrolls to the location of the first match.  Something like:

```
if
    let searchTerm = self.searchTerm,
    let range = self.formattedText.range(of: searchTerm, options: .caseInsensitive)
{
    //scroll text to range
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: UIKit would be much better for this